# How to start jenkins?

Tags: services, upstart, init, jenkins

I installed `jenkins` via `sudo apt-get install jenkins`. However, it doesn't start up. Tried to start it manually using `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start`. But it shows this message when I try to start it that way:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.67" (uid=1000 pid=7970 comm="start jenkins ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")"
```

`init.d` method just says `starting`, but never starts...

How do I fix this and get jenkins to start up?

Answer (score 5):

Check the jenkins upstart configuration file `/etc/init/jenkins.conf`.

Verify that the path for `JAVA_HOME` is correct.  On a fresh install, it may look like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-default` (or default-java), however, if you've used apt-get to install the java 6 jre, the directory is actually `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`

Answer (score 1):

If you change `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr` in `/etc/init/jenkins.conf` then you can use whichever Java implementation you like.

You can see your altenative installations of java with (as root - add sudo if need be):

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

You can set your java alternative with:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```